# What's the best 3D graphics library for Java web apps?

Tags: java, web-applications, graphics, 3d

I'm looking for a 3D graphics library for a Java web app. Could use some recommendations - only open source, though.

Edit: I don't really care how the graphics are output - Javascript/applets/canvas/flash but I want to write the graphics logic in Java.

Comment: I'm unable to understand the concept of a "3D graphics web app".

Comment: Bennop, do you mean for use in Applets?

Comment: I don't really care how the graphics are output - Javascript/applets/canvas/flash but I want to write the graphics logic in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JMonkeyEngine is very good.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the *The Lightweight Java Game Library*. It provided developers access to crossplatform libraries such as openGl. And can run in the browser.

- http://lwjgl.org

Here are a few demos:

- http://lwjgl.org/applet/
- http://fabiensanglard.net/Prototyp/index.php
- http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d-4.html

People are doing awesome projects with this library:
http://lwjgl.org/projects.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that describes how to use jmonkeyengine in an applet.

http://www.streamhead.com/tutorial-jmonkeyengine-applet-hardware-3d-in-the-browser/

(JMonkeyEngine is a rather nice 3d-engine)

Comment: "Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!" - Google Chrome

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The warning is probably because the page contains an applet, and the java plugin is targeted by hackers.  And sorry, I don't have time to write a nice summary. Feel free to do so.